# Excel - copying values between sheet based on values within a range

Tags: excel

I have no coding experience, just trying to pull together a function within a spreadsheet at work to save everyone a lot of time - would be great if anyone could help me!

So I have an excel workbook, which has multiple columns of values within one sheet, which I would like to copy across to another sheet. But I only want to copy specific columns, dependent on the presence of a value in a different column for each row.

So for example:
Sheet 1
[image: example spreadsheet]

So I'm looking for a way to check for the presence of ANY value (ie just not an empty cell) in column C, and if there is a value present in column C, to then copy the values from columns A and B into a separate sheet in the workbook. I would need it do this check for each row within sheet 1 and copy them all as separate rows into sheet 2.

Is this possible?? Ideally without the use of VBA as I have a feeling adding this in to an already shared workbook may slow it down to the point of not being able to be used?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Sheet1` is as follows

[image]

Then in `Cell A1` of `Sheet2` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C$1:C$5,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5))*ROW($C$1:$C$5),0),COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5)+ROW($C1))),"")
```

Drag/Copy down and across (to right) as required. Change range as per your data. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response - I'll try it on my spreadsheet today and let you know whether it works for the data range I'm looking at :)